# Restricting a portion of code through an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have built a ruby on rails app that lets users track their workouts. User has_many workouts. In addition, a User can create a box (gym) if they are a gym owner. The purpose is to filter activity of users such that they can only see information related to their gym. Users can then specify if they are a member of that box through a Membership model. The Membership table collects @box.id and current_user.id in the membership.box_id and user.id columns respectively.

The user associates through the following form in the /views/boxes/show.html.erb view:

```
<% remote_form_for Membership.new do |f| %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :box_id, :value => @box.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "I am a member of this box" , :class => '' %>
<% end %>
```

I then display, in the box show page all the users who are members of that box.

```
<% @box.users.each do |user| %>
  <%= link_to (user.username), user %><br/>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to restrict the form to only users who are not already members of that box but I am not sure how to write the `<% unless ... %>` statement.

Here are the rest of the associations:

User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boxes
  has_many :workouts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Workout

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Box

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :workouts, :through => :users
  has_many :memberships
end
```

Membership

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Comment: I guess some people will benefit from all the code, but it's just too much to read sometimes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Membership model
named_scope :for_box, lambda {|box| {:conditions => {:box_id => box.id}}}

# User model
has_many :memberships

def member_of_box?(box)
  !memberships.for_box(box).blank?
end

# View
<% unless current_user.member_of_box?(box) %>
   # Show the form
<% end %>
```

Disclaimer: The code is not tested. It *might* need minor alterations.

Comment: I'm getting an error. `undefined method `for_box' for #<Class:0x104c2df80>`

Comment: I have changed the `named_scope` definition to rails 2.3.x like. Hope this works. If you are using rails 3, the scope definition would be different. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html for more details.

Comment: I think we're close. I am getting a syntax error: `/Users/bgadoci/WODstack/app/models/membership.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting '}'
..., lambda {|box| :conditions => (:box_id => box.id)}
                              ^
/Users/bgadoci/WODstack/app/models/membership.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ')'
...ox| :conditions => (:box_id => box.id)}
                              ^`

Comment: Sorry again, my bad. I have updated the code. The named_scope conditions should be under `{``}` and not `(``)`

Comment: I took your most recent update and added another set of `{}` and it worked: `named_scope :for_box, lambda {|box| {:conditions => {:box_id => box.id}}}`. Awesome. Thanks for the help.