# Deleting an associated record through a remote_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, associations

I have built a ruby on rails app that lets users track their workouts. User has_many workouts. In addition, a User can create a box (gym) if they are a gym owner. Users can then associate with that box through a Membership resource.

I create that association for the current_user with a remote form in /views/boxes/show.html.erb:

```
<% remote_form_for Membership.new do |f| %> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :box_id, :value => @box.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "I am a member of this box" , :class => '' %>
<% end %>
```

I now want to give the current_user the ability to remove their association. How do I structure the link/form and what should the memberships_controller destroy action look like?

Below is a list of my associations if it helps:
User

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :boxes
  has_many :workouts, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Workout

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Box

```
class Box < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
  has_many :workouts, :through => :users
  has_many :memberships
end
```

Membership

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :box
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have done the changes suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331751/restricting-a-portion-of-code-through-an-association/4331942#4331942), and assuming that you have obtained the membership for the current_user and the box using the following code,

```
@membership = current_user.memberships.for_box(box).first
```

create a link for the user to delete the membership as follows.

```
link_to 'Delete Membership', membership_path(@membership), :method => :delete
```

Membership controller should have a destroy method that looks like the following.

```
def destroy
  @membership = Membership.find(params[:id])
  @membership.destroy
end
```

This is assuming that your memberships controller is restful and you have `map.resources :memberships` in your routes.

Comment: Can you give me some specifics on the form? I tried simply changing `<% remote_form_for Membership.new do |f| %>` to `<% remote_form_for Membership.destroy do |f| %>` but that give a `wrong number of arguments error`.

Comment: No I have a validation that says that can't have more than one membership period. Why do you ask?